# Is it possible to view last changes in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made some changes to functions,view, tables in my Postgresql db.

Sadly my pc shut down unexpectedly and I lost the change file.

However the changes are in my DB as I already run them.

Is there a way to get a list of recent changes (In code not in data) in postgresql DB?

Comment: log file ??.........

Comment: There are no timestamps on changes, nor is any history of changes kept. Except for using quite difficult forensic methods for data recovery (time consuming and expensive) you will only be able to get the information if you have `log_statement` set to record enough detail that the changes appeared in the log files.

Comment: do you maybe have a backup of older version of that database? you could run some database compare scripts to get differences between those db's